# Aurelia bundle and jspm config file

Tags: node.js, jspm, aurelia

I have an Aurelia app built with visual studio that uses npm and jspm for package managing. I have setted a `postinstall` rule on npm as follows:

`"postinstall": "jspm install -y & jspm init & aurelia bundle --force"`

This `postinstall` rule creates the `config.js` with all the mappings needed for aurelia but when it reaches `aurelia bundle --force` it crashes with the following error:

```
info: Creating bundle ...

err  Error: ENOENT, open '...\jspm_packages\github\aurelia\animatorcss@0.15.0\aurelia-animator-css' at Error (native)
```

If i modify manually the `config.js` file by adding `defaultJSExtensions: true` it runs perfectly and creates the bundle.

It is possible to add this property after i run `jspm install -y & jspm init` (because I don't want to modify it manually)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the post about [the latest release of Aurelia](http://blog.durandal.io/2015/08/05/aurelia-release-for-jspm-beta/) and after updating to jspm@beta by running `npm install -g jspm@beta` and reinstalling all the packages the problem was solved.

I then added `jspm@master` to my `package.json` file so I don't have to worry about installing jspm on other developers machines.